# GWT logging to file

Tags: gwt, tomcat, logging, log4j

I am writing my first GWT and i confess i have no idea how to set up loggers.

I am deploying the application to tomcat and want to be able to set up a logger so that i can log to a file in $catalina.home. Gwt came with logging.properties for a java util style log and log4j.properties; i have looked at documentation for the gwt java util logger and it seems to just write to console so it must be log4j i need?

In the past ive seen org.apache.log4j.Logger used, is this what i want?

Could somebody please point me to somewhere where this is documented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html). You can't use file appenders directly because the GWT code runs as Javascript in the browser (when not in development mode). If you want to log to a file you need to enable remote logging.

If there is a server side part logging works as normal. But then it has not much to do with GWT, except for being in the same project and providing services (via a custom protocol).

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to log? rpc service servlets or client logic?

Log4j is just for java not javascript. So it is intended to log your classes in your */server*/ package that will be deployed in your server.

Your */client*/ package classes will be translated to javascript and will run in the client browser. So, no Java at all!

You can use log4j "emulated" to javascript with http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/ which will send your client logs using a RemoteLogger to the server via rpc and then you can log them to a file.